# SHACL/ShEX constraint to make a property to build a hierarchy (i.e. a tree)

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, shacl, shex

I have very little knowledge of SHACL and ShEx.

I've been reading about them and to figure out whether I could create constraints over a property to make it define a hierarchy (i.e. a tree-like structure).

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to specify that, for a given property `p`,

a) this **can** happen (`o1 != o2`):

```
   s p o1 .
   s p o2 .
   ...
   s p oN
```

b) but this **cannot** (`s1 != s2`):

```
   s1 p o .
   s2 p o
```

I guess for a) I should use some kind of constraint on the cardinality of `p`, right?

No idea on how to specify b) or even if it is possible at all using either SHACL or ShEX. Should I be using OWL?

Comment: In OWL: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Inverse-Functional_Object_Properties

Comment: Though OWL axioms are not constraints but used for inference. So, having an inverse functional property axiom just infers `s1 owl:sameAs s2` and a contradiction only occurs if you explicitly make `s1` and `s2` distinct (or it follows from other axioms)

Comment: @UninformedUser Exactly, OWL seems to less concerned with constraints and more with adding informaton for inference. That's why I was looking into SHACL or ShEx for these kind of constraints...

Comment: Following @StanislavKralin suggestion, I found this: `sh:maxCount 1 on a sh:inversePath` suggested in https://spinrdf.org/shacl-and-owl.html. I'll try and see whether this solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In OWL**

Assuming `DifferentIndividuals: :s1, :s2` etc.:

```
ObjectProperty: :p
  Characteristics: InverseFunctional
```

**In ShEx**

With shape map like `{_ :p FOCUS} @ :Shape`:

```
:Shape { 
  ^:p IRI ?
}
```

[Example](http://rdfshape.herokuapp.com/validate?data=%40prefix%20%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%0A%3Aa%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ap%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ad%20%2C%20%3Ac%20.%0A%0A%3Ab%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ap%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ac%20.%0A&dataFormat=turtle&schema=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%0A%0A%3AShape%20%7B%20%0A%20%5E%3Ap%20IRI%20%3F%0A%7D%0A&schemaFormat=ShExC&schemaEngine=ShEx&triggerMode=ShapeMap&schemaEmbedded=false&inference=NONE&activeDataTab=%23dataTextArea&activeSchemaTab=%23schemaTextArea&activeShapeMapTab=%23shapeMapTextArea&&shapeMap=%7B_%20%3Ap%20FOCUS%7D%40%3AShape)

**In SHACL**

```
:Shape a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetObjectsOf :p ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path [ sh:inversePath :p ] ;
    sh:maxCount 1 
  ] .
```

[Example](http://rdfshape.herokuapp.com/validate?data=%40prefix%20%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%0A%3Aa%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ap%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ad%20%2C%20%3Ac%20.%0A%0A%3Ab%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ap%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ac%20.%0A&dataFormat=turtle&schema=prefix%20%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%3E%20%0Aprefix%20sh%3A%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fshacl%23%3E%20%0A%0A%3AShape%20a%20sh%3ANodeShape%20%3B%0A%20%20sh%3AtargetObjectsOf%20%3Ap%20%3B%0A%20%20sh%3Aproperty%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20sh%3Apath%20%5B%20sh%3AinversePath%20%3Ap%20%5D%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sh%3AmaxCount%201%20%3B%0A%20%20%5D%20.&schemaFormat=Turtle&schemaEngine=SHACLex&triggerMode=TargetDecls&schemaEmbedded=false&inference=NONE&activeDataTab=%23dataTextArea&activeSchemaTab=%23schemaTextArea&activeShapeMapTab=%23shapeMapTextArea&&shapeMap=)

**In pure SPARQL**

```
ASK { ?o ^:p ?s1, ?s2 . FILTER (?s1 != ?s2) }
```

**In general**

Read ["Validating RDF Data"](https://book.validatingrdf.com/).